# Why using MKLocalSearch returns an error and fails to load the expected results?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, mapkit, osx-mavericks

I'm developing a Mac OS X app, in Mavericks, and I've been receiving an error while executing the following code:

```
MKLocalSearchRequest *request = [[MKLocalSearchRequest alloc] init];
request.naturalLanguageQuery = @"Pizza Hut";
MKLocalSearch *search = [[MKLocalSearch alloc] initWithRequest:request];

[search startWithCompletionHandler:^(MKLocalSearchResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    if (response.mapItems.count == 0)
        NSLog(@"No Matches");
    else
        for (MKMapItem *item in response.mapItems) {
            NSLog(@"name = %@", item.name);
        }
}];
```

I'm just trying to search for "Pizza Hut" using `MKLocalSearch`, without setting any `region` on `MKLocalSearchRequest` so I can get global results, not just places near me. But this code fails to execute and I get the following error in my console:

> PBRequester failed with Error Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=1
>   "The operation couldn’t be completed. Operation not permitted"
>   UserInfo=0x60800067d680
>   {NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://gsp-ssl.ls.apple.com/search.arpc,
>   NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://gsp-ssl.ls.apple.com/search.arpc}

And, therefore, `"No Matches"` is printed in my console.
Any ideas on why is this happening? I have Maps turned on in `Capabilites`, I have the `MapKit.framework` and I have the `com.apple.developer.map` key in my Entitlements. Is something missing here? Thanks!

Comment: Could this be due to sandboxing and missing entitlements? Check https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/security/conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/AboutAppSandbox/AboutAppSandbox.html for details

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to enable the "Outgoing Connections (Client)" network entitlement to get Location Services working.

My minimal entitlements file for an OS X app using MKLocalSearch looks as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>com.apple.security.app-sandbox</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.network.client</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.personal-information.location</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Sadly Apple's [Entitlement Key Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/EntitlementKeyReference/Chapters/EnablingAppSandbox.html) doesn't mention this. Maybe we should file a documentation bug.

Additionally, the Provisioning Profile that is used for code signing (Check "Build Settings" in your Target) has to have the "Maps" service enabled. You can check that in the "Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles" section of the Developer Portal:

[image]